# Reledmac prints the lemma in the text

Tags: reledmac, lemma

Why does reledmac print the lemma in the text, that is, where is written, in the source file:

```
Silius Italicus de Libya  \edtext{Libya}{\Afootnote{Libia \textit{E1}}} loquutus inquit
```

Latex prints in the pdf:

Silius Italicus de Libya Libya loquutus inquit

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,portuges,]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}

\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}

\Xarrangement[B]{twocol}

\usepackage{verse}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{gensymb}

\newcommand{\cmmnt}[1]{\ignorespaces}


\begin{document}

\part{Introdução}

\part{Edição}

\selectlanguage{latin}




\lineation{page}



\fnpos{critical-familiar}
\beginnumbering



\pstart
\textsc{Libri secvndi geographiae\footnoteB{Note-se variação do título em relação as livros anteriores nos códices: \textit{Liber secundus cosmotheoriae}} pars secvnda eam geographiae partem complectens qvam practicam lvbet appellare}
\pend


\pstart
\textsc{Svmma terrarvm orbis vniversi divisio Capvt primvm}
\pend


\pstart 
\lettrine[lines=2]{N}{on eum} seruabimus ordinem  in hac secunda huius operis parte, quem in sua Geographia Ptolomaeus. Temporis enim angustiis interclusi sola Africae, Asiae, Europaeque /f. 56r/ \edtext{maritima}{\Afootnote{<.>ari- \textit{non legitur E1}}} peragrabimus de sola Hispania \edtext{luculentius}{\Afootnote{locu- \textit{E1}}} acturi qua tandem perlustrata in Nouum Orbem, ni fata uetant, nobis erit enauigandum: omissa igitur diuisione ea, qua mundum in archetipum, et corporeum theologi partiuntur, atque etiam illa qua, corporeum in aetheream et elementarem regionem physici diuiserunt, eam solum eius partem  minutius partiemur quae solida et globosa et in sese nutibus suis undique conglobata medium locum centri \edtext{instar}{\Afootnote{-are \textit{E1}}} optinet \footnoteB{Cícero, \textit{Tusc.}, I, 40 e \textit{De natura deorum}, II, 98.}.
\pend


\pstart
Hanc porro ueteres uel ipso \edtext{Iustino}{\Afootnote{pristino \textit{ante corr.} Justino \textit{in marg.} \textit{E1}}} auctore, \textit{De bello Iugurtino}\footnoteB{Salústio, Jug.17.3}, cuius etiam meminit August. lib. 16 \textit{De ciuitate Dei} cap. 13  \footnoteB{Civ. Dei, XVI, 17} in duas tamen partes diuiserunt Asiam nempe et Europam: Africam enim uel Asiae partem constituebant uel Europae unde Silius Italicus de Libya  \edtext{Libya}{\Afootnote{Libia \textit{E1}}} loquutus inquit:
\begin{verse}
\poemlines{1}
Aut ingens Asiae latus, aut pars tertia rerum\footnoteB{Sílio Itálico, \textit{Pun.}, 1.195}
\end{verse}
et Lucanus lib. 9:
\begin{verse}
\poemlines{4}
Tertia pars rerum Libye si credere famae \par
cuncta uelis: at si ventos, caelumque sequaris \par
pars erit Europae; neque enim plus litora Nilli \par
quam Scythicus Tanais primis a Gadibus absunt. \footnoteB{Lucano, 9.411-4}
\end{verse}
quo pacto orbem terrarum in orientalem occidentalemque partem diuidebant duas praecipuas caeli plagas sequuti uentosque Eurum, qui ex aequinoctiali solis \edtext{ortu}{\Afootnote{-tus \textit{E1}}}  eflat, /f. 56v/ et \edtext{Zephyrum}{\Afootnote{Zefer- \textit{E1}}}, qui ab aequinoctiali occasu: septimo igitur meridiano qui per Nilli Tanaisque paene  \edtext{paene}{\Afootnote{pene \textit{E1}}}  fauces ducitur et Europam uniuersam, Africamque occidentem uersus relinquit. Asiam uero ad orientem terram totam partiebantur, quo loco non satis miror \edtext{alucinentur}{\Afootnote{hal- \textit{E1}}} Lucani  \edtext{interpretes}{\Afootnote{-praet- \textit{E1}}}  his in carminibus  \edtext{enucleandis}{\Afootnote{-cli- \textit{E1}}}.
\pend

\pstart
Alii in quattuor diuisere partes, Europam, Africam, Aegyptum et Asiam. Aegypti namque nonnulli ueterum insulam fuisse tradiderunt, ut uel Plinius refert, lib. 5 \footnoteB{Plínio, NA, 5.48.5-6} suae Naturalis Historiae cap. 9. Recentiores tamen geographi in tres, Asiam, Africam et Europam quarum singulis uicinas adnectunt insulas.
\pend

\pstart
Nos uero non longe aliter orbem diuidemus in Nouum nempe Orbem, Veterem et Terram Ignis ut uocant cuius hactenus solum nomen notum est. Nouum deinde Orbem siue Americam in Australem, et Borealem: Australem in Brasiliam, Terram Gigantum, \edtext{Peruuiam}{\Afootnote{\textit{lectio difficilis} \textit{E1}}},  \edtext{Hispaniam}{\Afootnote{-niam \textit{post corr.} -neam \textit{ante corr.} \textit{E1}}}  Auream; Borealem rursus in Nouam Hispaniam, Nouam Galisiam, Floridam in Baccaleorum regionem et in Terram Agricolae: Veterem Orbem in Asiam, Africam et Europam, tamen suis singulis adnectens insulas.
\pend

\pstart 
\textsc{Generalis totius Africae diuisio. Caput secundum}
\pend

\pstart 
Quae Libia antea dicta est a Lybia eius regina /f. 57r/  \edtext{Epaphique}{\Afootnote{Ephanique \textit{E1}}} Iouis filii \edtext{coniunge}{\Afootnote{nepote \textit{cancellatum} \textit{E1}}}   Africa uocari coepit ab Afro Abrahami nepote, a quo etiam est ui et ferro domita auctore Iosepho lib. 1 De Antiquitatibus Iudaicis. Mediterraneo deinde mari a septentrione Oceano ab occidente a meridie et fere ab oriente circunscribitur, paeninsulae (\edtext{paeninsulae}{\Afootnote{pen- \textit{post corr.} \textit{E1}}} formam retinet), breuique  \edtext{isthmo}{\Afootnote{-thymo(-mo \textit{post corr.} -ma \textit{ante corr.} \textit{E1}}} mediterraneo mari extremoque sinu Arabico;  \edtext{hinc}{\Afootnote{hinc \textit{post corr.} hunc  \textit{ante corr.} \textit{E1}}} inde intercepto maiori Asiae adhaerescit [intercepta?], quare uero in illa diuidenda sibi non satis constant auctores tu illam diuides in citra Nilum, et ultra Nilum deinde \edtext{Africam citra Nilum}{\lemma{Africa \dots Nilum}\Afootnote{Nilum \textit{post corr.} Ninum \textit{ante corr.}  \textit{E1}}}  in Barbariam, Numidiam quae incolis dicitur Biledulgerid, Libyam  \edtext{Libyam}{\Afootnote{Lybiam \textit{E1}}} et  \edtext{Nigritarum}{\Afootnote{\textit{post corr.} \textit{E1}}} ut uocant tractum:
\pend

\pstart
Non longe in Oceanum influit Auri fluuius uulgo \textit{Rio de Ouro}, inde ad \textit{Angra de Gonsalo de Cyntra} leucae 14. non procul Blancum promontorium, inde ad insulam de Geth. unam ex iis, quae ad Arg[u]im castrum, pertinent, continentique admodum uicinam duodecim sunt leucae, conditum uero a Lusitanis est castrum de Arg[u]im, anno a Christo nato 1561 [1461], ad quod etiam pertinent uicinae insulae Naar et Tider \edtext{Naar et Tider}{\Afootnote{Nantider \textit{sic E1}}} et \textit{ilha das Garsas}, sequitur indeque promontorium Sanctae Anae a quo ad flumen Sanaga \edtext{flumen Sanaga}{\Afootnote{Sanagato \textit{ante corr. E1}}} 50 leucae numerantur. Sanaga fluuio cuius fauces latitudinem habent borealem quindecim graduum et semis diuiduntur Asaneges \edtext{Asaneges}{\Afootnote{à Saneges \textit{sic E1}}} Mauri a Jalofis quorum imperium terminatur flumine Gambria, hic uero qua parte in Oceanum influit latitudinem habet tredecim graduum cum dimidio alterius: de utroque hoc flumine legendus erit Barrius in sua \textit{Asia}, decadis primae lib. 3 /58v/ cap. 6 et 8; inter haec duo flumina interiacet celebre illud promontorium apud Lusitanos, Ptolomaeo Arsinarium promontorium uulgo \textit{Cabo Verde} cuius latitudo est 14 graduum cum 3ª parte alterius.
A promontorio Arsinario ad Magnum usque fluuium uulgo ho Grande rio sexaginta et eo amplius leucae, inde uero ad fluuium Noni uulgo rio do Nuno uiginti numerantur, intercepto deinde non longo admodum tractu \edtext{non ... tractu}{\Afootnote{\textit{post corr.} tractu  longo non admodum \textit{ante corr. E1}}} sese offert \edtext{tractu sese offert}{\Afootnote{\textit{supra lineam E1}}} Rupes Leaenae \edtext{Leaenae}{\Afootnote{Leenae \textit{E1}}}, uulgo Serra Leoa, quae latitudinem habet septem graduum cum duobus tertiis.
Totam eam Africae oram maritimam, quae a promontorio Boiador usque ad Serra Leoa [iacet], exploratam \edtext{exploratam}{\Afootnote{exploratum \textit{E1}}} relinquit Lusitanus Infans Henricus Ioannis primi Lusitaniae regis filius tertius, in qua exploranda quadraginta integros annos absumpsit ab anno nempe a Christo nato 1423 usque ad 13um nouembris anni 1463 quo annum agens 67 diem clausit extremum \edtext{extremum}{\Afootnote{\textit{post corr.} extremit \textit{sic ante corr. E1}}} in Sagres oppido prope Sacrum promontorium.
\pend



\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because that is the way reledmac is designed to work (as explained in both handbook and examples). You don't need to repeat the lemma.

Just do

`Silius Italicus de  \edtext{Libya}{\Afootnote{Libia \textit{E1}}} loquutus inquit`